# what is the relation between GenricServlet and ServletConfig?

Tags: servlets

A `GenericServlet` is a type of `ServletConfig`, also `GenericServlet` has a `ServletConfig`. What is logic in this? How should I understand this?

```
public abstract class GenericServlet implements Servlet, ServletConfig, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient ServletConfig config;
    ..
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ServletConfig is an interface and is implemented by services in order to pass configuration information to a servlet when it is first loaded.

GenericServlet implements ServletConfig. It's not a subclass of ServletConfig. Understand the difference between a subclass and interface.

Answer (score 0):

GenericServlet class implements Servlet, ServletConfig and Serializable interfaces. It provides the implementation of all the methods of these interfaces except the service method.

GenericServlet class can handle any type of request so it is protocol-independent.

You may create a generic servlet by inheriting the GenericServlet class and providing the implementation of the service method.
Visit [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/genericservlet-servletconfig.html?m=1) for more